# It is impossible to create a new session because ‘createSession’ which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, appium

This is my code but got error

> "It is impossible to create a new session because ‘createSession’ which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible"

```
DesiredCapabilities Cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
    Cap.setCapability("PlatformName", "Android");
    Cap.setCapability("deviceName", "ABC");
    Cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
    Cap.setCapability("app", "APK_path");
    Cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.myera.MainActivity");
    Cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.myera");
    //Cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
    Cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");
    //Cap.setCapability("fullReset", "false");
    AndroidDriver D=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),Cap);
```

Comment: did you start appium server before you ran this code? I mean to is server at url(http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub) is up and running?

Comment: You can check the appium log for the exact issue. I suggest you too see the few line before above error message displayed,